# Optimization. How to speed up the given C ++ code?

Tags: c++, optimization

> This is my code. 1<=i<=j<=n j-i<=a 1<=n<=1000000 0<=a<=1000000

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, a, r = 0;
    cin>>n>>a;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int j = i;
        for(j; j <= n; j++){
            if(j-i<=a){
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<r;
}
```

> Instead of loops, I changed it to a simple check of variables, which greatly accelerated the code. there is no need to calculate thousands of options.
> My final, optimized code is:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned long long n, a, r = 0;
    cin>>n>>a;
    if(a==0){
        r = n;
    }
    if(n<=a){
        r = (n*(n+1))/2;    
    }
    if(n>a){
        r += (n-a)*(a+1) + (a*(a+1))/2;
    }
    cout<<r;
}
```

Comment: *How to speed up the given C ++ code?* -- Use a totally different approach.   You should have seen using a nested `for` loop would be hopeless, given the possible value of `n`. 
 What is the actual question you are trying to solve?

Comment: Think about the problem. If i and j are the row and column number in a matrix that stores j-j at each given position. Write down this matrix and try to think about what is being counted in your loop. There should be a solution not involving any loop at all. Or in Big-O notation: you can bring down this from O(n^2) to O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After accounting for both positive numbers, negative numbers, and zeros, your double-nested for-loop can be simplified into this:

```
if (n < 1)
{
    r = 0;
}
else if (a == 0)
{
    r = n;
}
else if (a < 0)
{
    r = 0;
}
else if (n <= a)
{
    r = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
else
{
    r = (n-a)*(a + 1) + (a * (a + 1)) / 2;
}
```

Recall that summing a sequence of digits from `1..N` is:

```
 N*(N+1)
 -------
    2
```

If `n <= a` (positive numbers), `r` is incremented `n` times in the inner loop on the first iteration of the outer loop. Then `n-1` times, then `n-2` times... all the way down to `1`.

For cases where `n > a`, then there are `n-a` summations of `a+1` followed by a decrementing summation from `a` down to `1`

Comment: Your solution is perfect. It's enough for me to check that n <= a, or n> a. Because initially, positive integers are entered. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as something to speed up by doing a bit of math, not by massaging the code.

Basically, we can think of the loops as defining a square matrix of the values of i and j. So let's assume n = 9, and a = 3. I'll draw in a `+` for each place we increment `r`, a blank for the values we don't generate, and a `0` for the places we generate values, but don't increment `r`.

```
i\j 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1   + + + + 0 0 0 0 0 
2     + + + + 0 0 0 0 
3       + + + + 0 0 0 
4         + + + + 0 0 
5           + + + + 0 
6             + + + +
7               + + +
8                 + + 
9                   +
```

So, ignoring the last `a` rows (i.e., for the first `n-a` rows), in each row we have a band `a + 1` elements wide where we do an increment. Then at the end, we have a triangle, where we're basically summing a + a-1 + a-2 ... 0.

So, the first piece is `(a+1) * (n-a)` and the second piece is `a * (a+1) / 2`. Add those together, and we get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

```
    for(j; j <= n; j++){
        if(j-i<=a){
            r++;
        }
    }
```

could be replaced by

```
   r += f(i,n,a);
```

Where f() is some simple expression involving those 3 values, probably including the equivalent of `min(..,..)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up your code, instead of just tuning your algorithm, you can also try to use some parallel api.

Parallel computing api such as OpenMP enables you take advantage of your cpu resources.

If you uses OpenMP, you can try to use it to parallel your loop.